# Call page but nothing appears

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm back on the C# .net wfp application,

I have my MainWindows, and when I try ty call a new page, the wpf xaml doesn't appear.

this my code:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartingPage go = new StartingPage(/*NO PARAMS*/);
    }
```

and

```
public partial class StartingPage : Page
{
    public StartingPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show("HELLO");

    }
  ...
}
```

So, the `MessageBox` is called, but the content of my xaml view doesn't appears ...
( There it is:

```
<Page x:Class="..."
                ...
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="StartingPage" ShowsNavigationUI="True">

      <Grid Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuBarBrushKey}}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtName" Grid.Row="0" MinWidth="50" Margin="344,87,340.333,-35.667" Text="Welcome To TILKEE !&#xD;&#xA;" RenderTransformOrigin="1.293,1.602" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    <Button Content="Sign Up !&#xD;&#xA;" Grid.Row="0" Click="Button_Sign" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="211,199,211.333,-145.667"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtName_Copy" Grid.Row="0" MinWidth="50" Margin="372,277,371.333,-226.333" Text="  - Or -&#xA;" RenderTransformOrigin="1.293,1.602" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    <Button Content="Log in&#xA;" Grid.Row="0" Click="Button_Login" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="211,347,211.333,-291.333"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Enter Name :" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />


</Grid>
```

)

Comment: Try the Loaded event instead of the constructor

Comment: Hum, how I do that ?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057422/creating-pages-or-windows-in-wpf).

Comment: This tell me that NavigationService.Navigate need "An object reference is required for the non-static field" ... idea?

Comment: @F4Ke you are already have this object in "go" variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding a frame in  main window

```
 <Frame x:Name="frame1"></Frame>
```

on code behind write this

```
 frame1.NavigationService.Navigate(new StartingPage());
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have initialized StartingPage by creating object, the flow executes as

- Reads App.xaml the Startup attribute is read. (Default it is MainWindow.xaml)
- Default constructor execution take place where you have created the object.
- You need to write in next line

  go.Show();
- this will display StartingPage page
- after displaying it will also load MainWindow